# Passing PHP Array to AJAX and displaying them on the screen

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I would like to make my website more interactive. I have registration form, and I would like to display icons (correct/false) after the register button has been clicked so the user can see what field is not correct.

[image]

I know that I need to use `json_encode` to pass an array via ajax.

This is an example of my php code which I would like to use to control the registration form.

```
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
$errors = array();
$user = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if(empty($user)){
    $errors[] = "You need to fill username.";
}
if(strlen($password) < 3){
    $errors[] = "This Password is to short";
}
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $errors[] = "This e-mail is not correct ";
}

if(empty($errors)){
    $db->query("INSERT INTO users (user,pass,email)VALUES ('$user','$password','$email')");
}

if(!empty($errors)){
    json_encode($errors);
}
}
```

I don't want refresh page.

Comment: Look into json_encode becuase that's what you need `ech json_encode($errors);` Write the array to your client.

Comment: Are you actually making an ajax call? You should post the javascript as well. And you would need `json_encode`, not `json_decode`.

Comment: Yes It was mistake Niels.Jeroen I have no idea how to do it. I was trying few times but I couldn't get anything good enough

Answer (score 0):

in your `ajax_success_handler(data)` you have to parse the incoming data with `JSON.parse(data)`